# Python pip attemps to install every single version of package and fails

Tags: python, pip

I honestly don't know exactly what is going wrong, but when i try to install any package it tries to download the latest version, a yellow warning shows up (and sometimes a red one), then it attempts to install previous and the cycle just repeats until a final error is shown:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <PACKAGE>
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <PACKAGE>
```

Here's the output when i try to install `colored`:

```
$ pip install colored
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting colored
  Using cached colored-1.4.3.tar.gz (29 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/57/fe3e4e96efa3c68d3781a0903de0933ea2afa744852d907b290a2cb2294e/colored-1.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=b7b48b9f40e8a65bbb54813d5d79dd008dc8b8c5638d5bbfd30fc5a82e6def7a (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/57/fe3e4e96efa3c68d3781a0903de0933ea2afa744852d907b290a2cb2294e/colored-1.4.3.tar.gz#sha256=b7b48b9f40e8a65bbb54813d5d79dd008dc8b8c5638d5bbfd30fc5a82e6def7a has inconsistent version: filename has '1.4.3', but metadata has '1.4.3'
  Using cached colored-1.4.2.tar.gz (56 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/16/04827e24c14266d9161bd86bad50069fea453fa006c3d2b31da39251184a/colored-1.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=056fac09d9e39b34296e7618897ed1b8c274f98423770c2980d829fd670955ed (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/16/04827e24c14266d9161bd86bad50069fea453fa006c3d2b31da39251184a/colored-1.4.2.tar.gz#sha256=056fac09d9e39b34296e7618897ed1b8c274f98423770c2980d829fd670955ed has inconsistent version: filename has '1.4.2', but metadata has '1.4.2'
  Using cached colored-1.4.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/28/757731f5a6023649064d976913d588da060678c50a20e9dc4abed5aedeb4/colored-1.4.1.tar.gz#sha256=2468361d777160498cd6db6c47c41bf67ed1029723c4acabae512bedc021c961 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/28/757731f5a6023649064d976913d588da060678c50a20e9dc4abed5aedeb4/colored-1.4.1.tar.gz#sha256=2468361d777160498cd6db6c47c41bf67ed1029723c4acabae512bedc021c961 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.4.1', but metadata has '1.4.1'
  Using cached colored-1.4.0.tar.gz (27 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/6d/ec2a0b4a2ab86d0612f9cf11358fdffad9766375da18e15ac24e57654165/colored-1.4.0.tar.gz#sha256=ee8f73c40c06d9e5b829a8e284ebfaeac5ebfc7578f2eb4a0e031b40fe799a72 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/6d/ec2a0b4a2ab86d0612f9cf11358fdffad9766375da18e15ac24e57654165/colored-1.4.0.tar.gz#sha256=ee8f73c40c06d9e5b829a8e284ebfaeac5ebfc7578f2eb4a0e031b40fe799a72 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.4.0', but metadata has '1.4.0'
  Using cached colored-1.3.93.tar.gz (24 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/07/636616667b47d3115b0288311511c5fb446d0e499036b7db858704c89066/colored-1.3.93.tar.gz#sha256=8296ea990e3f6b7822f44eec21408b126dfb9c1c031306b859e3f7d46cc27075 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/07/636616667b47d3115b0288311511c5fb446d0e499036b7db858704c89066/colored-1.3.93.tar.gz#sha256=8296ea990e3f6b7822f44eec21408b126dfb9c1c031306b859e3f7d46cc27075 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.93', but metadata has '1.3.93'
  Using cached colored-1.3.92.tar.gz (23 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/f6/33030913d4796c41e45762a4b8a9eecdd4d052b925787808170cbc3889c3/colored-1.3.92.tar.gz#sha256=6fdb6bccf22542228ceb762e6b7048295a51b9c212e9173582f8f355638f6a3f (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/f6/33030913d4796c41e45762a4b8a9eecdd4d052b925787808170cbc3889c3/colored-1.3.92.tar.gz#sha256=6fdb6bccf22542228ceb762e6b7048295a51b9c212e9173582f8f355638f6a3f has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.92', but metadata has '1.3.92'
  Using cached colored-1.3.9.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_43b6766bb0a34c648807a0b70eda973b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_43b6766bb0a34c648807a0b70eda973b/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bxflgsxs
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_43b6766bb0a34c648807a0b70eda973b/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_43b6766bb0a34c648807a0b70eda973b/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.rst").read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/14/e9c100eaa9dec369bfbf5bde3dbba93da8d2b107de9a7e49a781ba22140c/colored-1.3.9.tar.gz#sha256=19debf00deb9673ec94c045ac700d47017e4a2f862632badaf492ebc0aba2f8d (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached colored-1.3.8.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_aecc50ac088b4c60a4543f1cd1613590/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_aecc50ac088b4c60a4543f1cd1613590/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-mxtp6va5
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_aecc50ac088b4c60a4543f1cd1613590/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_aecc50ac088b4c60a4543f1cd1613590/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.rst").read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/ef/531a3adf168d0ff07a7799a2f94f1f36afc1a386cd359310b2f2dc512a4f/colored-1.3.8.tar.gz#sha256=d88b6956edf10be489bf457c4a90cb6a11613c116cf3f0f0ef8efd97ea3c1a4e (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached colored-1.3.7.tar.gz (9.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f73eb07da41841599368af78455555ff/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f73eb07da41841599368af78455555ff/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-2713y28t
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f73eb07da41841599368af78455555ff/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f73eb07da41841599368af78455555ff/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.rst").read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/f7/efba3f5a969da328bf59e48a4056ae4e7bccee236649ec21da8275c953d2/colored-1.3.7.tar.gz#sha256=822697de8c4d07eb5b55309280388a82cbff18327be004aa980d07ff1afa4ba8 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached colored-1.3.6.tar.gz (9.8 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f0ae777f242542db89e41edf44c38d85/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f0ae777f242542db89e41edf44c38d85/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-yrp7kzry
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f0ae777f242542db89e41edf44c38d85/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_f0ae777f242542db89e41edf44c38d85/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        long_description=open("README.rst").read()
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/b7/13d0174b1dfb84eff0c4e106a3dc5ef8fd99e1c144e52046d0a9c24da21d/colored-1.3.6.tar.gz#sha256=b1b0291e9969b5f6fc0405469ea88b2369ab8fc2aef61ceb2f3ba2133cd1915f (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Downloading colored-1.3.5.tar.gz (36 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/be/85e6c8c1fd9b3d15d4500531ccbb164854d427690ad41c9ce9222ccabaf5/colored-1.3.5.tar.gz#sha256=84fb1c1e6686d94232a14ab1abec146af0c72f756067ea684bc401ec1f4b442b (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/19/be/85e6c8c1fd9b3d15d4500531ccbb164854d427690ad41c9ce9222ccabaf5/colored-1.3.5.tar.gz#sha256=84fb1c1e6686d94232a14ab1abec146af0c72f756067ea684bc401ec1f4b442b has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.5', but metadata has '1.3.5'
  Downloading colored-1.3.4.tar.gz (36 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/a0/42530898e7ba7fff883f11878b5617badd38ce72e9867ee3758019f3eca0/colored-1.3.4.tar.gz#sha256=0af33a6bb16d8b2dc820c8350b503bbe1cab4ef87c8aad9ae716fd00b7d04f52 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/a0/42530898e7ba7fff883f11878b5617badd38ce72e9867ee3758019f3eca0/colored-1.3.4.tar.gz#sha256=0af33a6bb16d8b2dc820c8350b503bbe1cab4ef87c8aad9ae716fd00b7d04f52 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.4', but metadata has '1.3.4'
  Downloading colored-1.3.3.tar.gz (36 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/e2/f5cb1c60d5e7baa6b828644845798539490a8632218b6ba5b21735633894/colored-1.3.3.tar.gz#sha256=a7b90a90d68094df8e6fe13c16c0307f9ab236abb0c73c73c60f15f265ee2cff (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/e2/f5cb1c60d5e7baa6b828644845798539490a8632218b6ba5b21735633894/colored-1.3.3.tar.gz#sha256=a7b90a90d68094df8e6fe13c16c0307f9ab236abb0c73c73c60f15f265ee2cff has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.3', but metadata has '1.3.3'
  Downloading colored-1.3.2.tar.gz (36 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/06/8dfb2c6a7dfcc32e5c5889b1cdfd98f2133d84bf45e574f5be4dc6db0516/colored-1.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=f784231cfde10e23ee42d77ee729d4e3249371841c2799fc5b2c4c1203a99a00 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/06/8dfb2c6a7dfcc32e5c5889b1cdfd98f2133d84bf45e574f5be4dc6db0516/colored-1.3.2.tar.gz#sha256=f784231cfde10e23ee42d77ee729d4e3249371841c2799fc5b2c4c1203a99a00 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.2', but metadata has '1.3.2'
  Downloading colored-1.3.1.tar.gz (33 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/34/ce9f46165630481b3e88f82d6d56aef9800aa6fe594bea6d626eee38b919/colored-1.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=2f15076e2e484dcbdd8809f87d51eec42b7da82b23a10a49068cf69ba0f38729 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/34/ce9f46165630481b3e88f82d6d56aef9800aa6fe594bea6d626eee38b919/colored-1.3.1.tar.gz#sha256=2f15076e2e484dcbdd8809f87d51eec42b7da82b23a10a49068cf69ba0f38729 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.1', but metadata has '1.3.1'
  Downloading colored-1.3.0.tar.gz (33 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/d4/8fd8ef20cef8efa3e6b696c3412e7bd6f90aa0e117106a0cbbc55cade687/colored-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=ac3d192f40b3a6e7f76339b19529111fd8720fb2440015c74a763d82511278f4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/d4/8fd8ef20cef8efa3e6b696c3412e7bd6f90aa0e117106a0cbbc55cade687/colored-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=ac3d192f40b3a6e7f76339b19529111fd8720fb2440015c74a763d82511278f4 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.3.0', but metadata has '1.3.0'
  Downloading colored-1.2.2.tar.gz (35 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/f5/1456d5e73a0ec307710f453fde321a7b6d4b7219f401f4d50c409c9c1198/colored-1.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=5e989801175c98123e0fd49745347ff537400c3004e2e6ac4a09400dd13ec43a (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/46/f5/1456d5e73a0ec307710f453fde321a7b6d4b7219f401f4d50c409c9c1198/colored-1.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=5e989801175c98123e0fd49745347ff537400c3004e2e6ac4a09400dd13ec43a has inconsistent version: filename has '1.2.2', but metadata has '1.2.2'
  Downloading colored-1.2.1.tar.gz (37 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/8e/f29d00c7b9885df88cfeb6148ccf50ad1b5bd7b591e8316283e602e65e1c/colored-1.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=55c7ccc9b775dc13e5b1f6bedeacab00f0e852cdd16aaf3569632cc20928ee56 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/8e/f29d00c7b9885df88cfeb6148ccf50ad1b5bd7b591e8316283e602e65e1c/colored-1.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=55c7ccc9b775dc13e5b1f6bedeacab00f0e852cdd16aaf3569632cc20928ee56 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.2.1', but metadata has '1.2.1'
  Downloading colored-1.2.0.tar.gz (36 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_76ea5d6826b049ceb36f22904c9b4776/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_76ea5d6826b049ceb36f22904c9b4776/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-cf55th59
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_76ea5d6826b049ceb36f22904c9b4776/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_76ea5d6826b049ceb36f22904c9b4776/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from colored import __version__
      File "/tmp/pip-install-9vp384o5/colored_76ea5d6826b049ceb36f22904c9b4776/colored/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from fore import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fore'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/69/bf8e166c8a7459b056ef1def50fae633aa6be87126fd1c187f9c9676d0fa/colored-1.2.0.tar.gz#sha256=4eba022e3e588d31ebe7d539b911d77a2bca3e9e366e121accca50b3c8eb6897 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Downloading colored-1.1.5.tar.gz (39 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/92/fa190bf6b18a16a72545768d0840572f46be43ac054f76b1bba1c560fb85/colored-1.1.5.tar.gz#sha256=a3660e46961a1a15de858354d2fa81a1374bfb6a7119d304faea6c34afd73be4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/92/fa190bf6b18a16a72545768d0840572f46be43ac054f76b1bba1c560fb85/colored-1.1.5.tar.gz#sha256=a3660e46961a1a15de858354d2fa81a1374bfb6a7119d304faea6c34afd73be4 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.5', but metadata has '1.1.5'
  Downloading colored-1.1.4.tar.gz (34 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fa/4eb38efb57a21ea3e1ce2ef2b1681d14decd6aab01f8dfa7a02f1d6b3a60/colored-1.1.4.tar.gz#sha256=067b1bcdc7bff42e68adb7c548d75d67ddf740e9cbd720ee9e40dc6fdfd72153 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/fa/4eb38efb57a21ea3e1ce2ef2b1681d14decd6aab01f8dfa7a02f1d6b3a60/colored-1.1.4.tar.gz#sha256=067b1bcdc7bff42e68adb7c548d75d67ddf740e9cbd720ee9e40dc6fdfd72153 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.4', but metadata has '1.1.4'
  Downloading colored-1.1.3.tar.gz (27 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/91/2c21546f2edc9490e691e8a81362b16455600d479fb775e853956f422869/colored-1.1.3.tar.gz#sha256=2aaf4d8eb6805629edcb3b15a0a957a86716352f620a95518a33cd3110fcb324 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/91/2c21546f2edc9490e691e8a81362b16455600d479fb775e853956f422869/colored-1.1.3.tar.gz#sha256=2aaf4d8eb6805629edcb3b15a0a957a86716352f620a95518a33cd3110fcb324 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.3', but metadata has '1.1.3'
  Downloading colored-1.1.2.tar.gz (28 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/d3/0a53524f21cc5474ad99316b4250ec5c7d32244bd517deee573cfee4fda5/colored-1.1.2.tar.gz#sha256=c366c3001146636fa6645d02b5334442c5072cfb55710d93566d67580d8baa89 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/d3/0a53524f21cc5474ad99316b4250ec5c7d32244bd517deee573cfee4fda5/colored-1.1.2.tar.gz#sha256=c366c3001146636fa6645d02b5334442c5072cfb55710d93566d67580d8baa89 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.2', but metadata has '1.1.1'
  Downloading colored-1.1.1.tar.gz (25 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/24/601aba433b69adb9469c73c2302edce4523c078236d7f80122e47818081f/colored-1.1.1.tar.gz#sha256=11618bdc0bf18f74b2faaaa57481a3951a8134289f6bb369343ac0780caa70a7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e1/24/601aba433b69adb9469c73c2302edce4523c078236d7f80122e47818081f/colored-1.1.1.tar.gz#sha256=11618bdc0bf18f74b2faaaa57481a3951a8134289f6bb369343ac0780caa70a7 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.1', but metadata has '1.1.1'
  Downloading colored-1.1.0.tar.gz (21 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/01/cb9f6b6d08ba0c7b383c9895099a20f6d90e567f021cc32a59aa2769684b/colored-1.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=18a6057c688a6c1a1a9bfbc91e0460759698323d260c6e0d2cf7b73291ec2275 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/01/cb9f6b6d08ba0c7b383c9895099a20f6d90e567f021cc32a59aa2769684b/colored-1.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=18a6057c688a6c1a1a9bfbc91e0460759698323d260c6e0d2cf7b73291ec2275 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.1.0', but metadata has '1.1.0'
  Downloading colored-1.0.9.tar.gz (19 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/d1/9e0985dc69c9be155c0ed721b0710c4a3a47ddc6d3e8f1f6f42e75780552/colored-1.0.9.tar.gz#sha256=71b9fd90bf66352b42c7b2fefc1523165347dfbe120c1ac576ab2261f24ad89d (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/68/d1/9e0985dc69c9be155c0ed721b0710c4a3a47ddc6d3e8f1f6f42e75780552/colored-1.0.9.tar.gz#sha256=71b9fd90bf66352b42c7b2fefc1523165347dfbe120c1ac576ab2261f24ad89d has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.9', but metadata has '1.0.9'
  Downloading colored-1.0.8.tar.gz (20 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/ae/9a8dc83329870ebd463587cd5e3649f12f03a509a0b4b15f0d52b138194e/colored-1.0.8.tar.gz#sha256=05956ded19f796b7991a7a90cdfcc6ae41f3445c89a60ed0fde1a509f3ea084c (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/ae/9a8dc83329870ebd463587cd5e3649f12f03a509a0b4b15f0d52b138194e/colored-1.0.8.tar.gz#sha256=05956ded19f796b7991a7a90cdfcc6ae41f3445c89a60ed0fde1a509f3ea084c has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.8', but metadata has '1.0.8'
  Downloading colored-1.0.7.tar.gz (20 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/3a/e9a7b5af9861d987fcdf10e470b3153e8d209f6058c038525a2578d096c5/colored-1.0.7.tar.gz#sha256=eb64f5054cdf00a85ec12c40d6a2b009e46a1b2ed0ee9d8bb3878aa07a8cff80 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/3a/e9a7b5af9861d987fcdf10e470b3153e8d209f6058c038525a2578d096c5/colored-1.0.7.tar.gz#sha256=eb64f5054cdf00a85ec12c40d6a2b009e46a1b2ed0ee9d8bb3878aa07a8cff80 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.7', but metadata has '1.0.7'
  Downloading colored-1.0.6.tar.gz (24 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/39/0ab8951f71e6e1ad23cdbef10449193134d440aa352f4477919009bc8b44/colored-1.0.6.tar.gz#sha256=c89265c5bc2b695614db14b3afd27c5e945db8a2847b85160b6e0336d34a2c8e (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/39/0ab8951f71e6e1ad23cdbef10449193134d440aa352f4477919009bc8b44/colored-1.0.6.tar.gz#sha256=c89265c5bc2b695614db14b3afd27c5e945db8a2847b85160b6e0336d34a2c8e has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.6', but metadata has '1.0.6'
  Downloading colored-1.0.5.tar.gz (15 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/e7/e872d806c60f9325b3b9bf514b99d5bcaa8a7c3a62b322d7ef6167ff95d9/colored-1.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=6f368f4281834856cce91aa3ab91f0631d459829e50d35c45cef665e8a7aed32 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/88/e7/e872d806c60f9325b3b9bf514b99d5bcaa8a7c3a62b322d7ef6167ff95d9/colored-1.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=6f368f4281834856cce91aa3ab91f0631d459829e50d35c45cef665e8a7aed32 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.5', but metadata has '1.0.5'
  Downloading colored-1.0.4.tar.gz (15 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/93/813de58a172ae64f348c075978cdfc1746fbf95ab8271e627d28ed977942/colored-1.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=5a0dbbde0aae253d4a113c9903b82df596b7e4757320c880a961a974a71ff4d6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/93/813de58a172ae64f348c075978cdfc1746fbf95ab8271e627d28ed977942/colored-1.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=5a0dbbde0aae253d4a113c9903b82df596b7e4757320c880a961a974a71ff4d6 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.4', but metadata has '1.0.4'
  Downloading colored-1.0.3.tar.gz (15 kB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/e9/000daa009c728d5a92885ad0eea8e145da8a1b10efdbc1355124d6343a2f/colored-1.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=73c3e612a43b4182d1ef429f917a6563fc140697e400bb24c277d114c0d42b51 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/e9/000daa009c728d5a92885ad0eea8e145da8a1b10efdbc1355124d6343a2f/colored-1.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=73c3e612a43b4182d1ef429f917a6563fc140697e400bb24c277d114c0d42b51 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.3', but metadata has '1.0.3'
  Downloading colored-1.0.2.tar.gz (214 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 214 kB 4.6 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/cc/fb6f1bbb76cf9bd5df78d2b0f8ea6ec5bef4fbc0fed05c3196c160e5a097/colored-1.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=e6560b86aacdc5f85401789082f0bc4b758559fc127fa450ae2bcdbe4db31fed (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/cc/fb6f1bbb76cf9bd5df78d2b0f8ea6ec5bef4fbc0fed05c3196c160e5a097/colored-1.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=e6560b86aacdc5f85401789082f0bc4b758559fc127fa450ae2bcdbe4db31fed has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.2', but metadata has '1.0.2'
  Downloading colored-1.0.1.tar.gz (108 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 108 kB 6.2 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/dc/6db0009d5937831ba66bf9d2fbbbeca91664e5f4fb4274a0d56af5acf3e4/colored-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=6a4da2eb55b48150ed3103ecb39c3145a7d864d6e6d6836f45dcf93867b93a0b (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/dc/6db0009d5937831ba66bf9d2fbbbeca91664e5f4fb4274a0d56af5acf3e4/colored-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=6a4da2eb55b48150ed3103ecb39c3145a7d864d6e6d6836f45dcf93867b93a0b has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.1', but metadata has '1.0.1'
  Downloading colored-1.0.0.tar.gz (123 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 123 kB 6.6 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/5f/54522b357d48c8672d8a83f0955da79c1e220fe693d3025198eb903efbc0/colored-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=758b79cf30c9e461af5ce745220ad132d511ae5f11aa87b99328f302b39ab203 (from https://pypi.org/simple/colored/). Requested colored from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/5f/54522b357d48c8672d8a83f0955da79c1e220fe693d3025198eb903efbc0/colored-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=758b79cf30c9e461af5ce745220ad132d511ae5f11aa87b99328f302b39ab203 has inconsistent version: filename has '1.0.0', but metadata has '1.0.0'
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement colored
ERROR: No matching distribution found for colored
```

this happens for every single package i try to install using pip, including pip itself. Doing `python -m pip install colored` or `python3 -m pip install colored` instead of `pip install colored` makes no difference. I'm running python 3.10.4 and pip 21.0 on Manjaro Linux. What exactly is going on and how could I fix it?

Comment: Try using `-v` to see the verbose output. If that doesn't tell much, use `-vvv` to get more information on what's going on. Since this is an issue with pip, maybe a clean install would fix it?

Comment: I download the [`.tar.gz` file from pypi](https://pypi.org/project/colored/#files) and extracted it. it includes the `README.rst` file. perhaps something is getting messed up with the working directory during `pip install` ? I also ran `python -m pip install -U colored==1.4.3` successfully on debian linux with python 3.9.12.

Comment: There might be issue with your current python version. Change Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by `M B` in the comments, it appears it was an issue with pip, as removing pip with pip and installing it again with `python -m ensurepip` fixed it.